# Getting all of a specific day between two dates - quickest method?

Tags: arrays, vb.net, performance, date

I'm looking at what the best and quickest method is to get all the days (mon, tues, weds) between two particular dates.

The days are passed as parameters to a webservice as a comma-delimited string, eg `mon,tue,wed,`

This is pseudo-code at the moment.

so my (psuedo)code would be as follows

```
function Add(startdate, enddate, days)
{
    dateList as New List(Of Date)
    if days.split(',').count < 7 then
    {
        // This is the problem area.

    }

    while(startdate < enddate)
    {
        // do some processing of either the dates in dateList or just all days
    }
}
```

This issue to me is do I

1)

- split the `days` parameter into an array,
- loop the the days array
- for each `day` in days:

  - go through each date between `startdate` and `enddate`
  - if `date.day`    is `day`, add to dateList
    in this method there are potentially (365 * 6) checks (assuming that start and end date are a year apart), also if all the days are selected, i can ignore putting them into a list

2)

- go through each date between `startdate` and `enddate`
- switch(date.dayofweek.tostring())
- case 'mon':if days.contains('mon') then addDatetoList

3)

- for each `everyday` between `startdate` and `enddate`
- if `days`.contains(everyday.dayofweek.tostring()) then addDatetoList

4) is there another method i've overlooked and all these are completely innefficient?

the calculation needs to take place in the vb.net codebehind, otherwise i'd think about using sql server to do it.

**EDIT**

As an exercise in function timing i've quickly built the following to try my and other methods out.

```
Dim DaysOfWeek As String = "Monday,Tuesday,Friday"
        Dim startDate As DateTime = DateTime.Now
        Dim endDate As DateTime = DateTime.Now.AddDays(365)
        Dim dateList As New List(Of DateTime)()

        Dim method1StopWatch As New Stopwatch
        Dim method2StopWatch As New Stopwatch
        Dim method3StopWatch As New Stopwatch
        Dim method4StopWatch As New Stopwatch

        Dim executionStart As Long
        Dim executionEnd As Long
        Dim noDays As Integer = 0

        'Method3

        method3StopWatch.Start()
        Do While (startDate < endDate)
            If DaysOfWeek.Contains(startDate.DayOfWeek.ToString()) Then
                dateList.Add(startDate)
                noDays = noDays + 1
            End If
            startDate = startDate.AddDays(1)

        Loop
        method3StopWatch.Stop()
        Label3.Text = method3StopWatch.ElapsedTicks.ToString() & " " & noDays & " Days"

        noDays = 0
        dateList.Clear()
        startDate = DateTime.Now

        'Method2

        method2StopWatch.Start()

        Do While (startDate < endDate)
            Select startDate.DayOfWeek.ToString()
                Case "Monday"
                    If DaysOfWeek.Contains("Monday") Then
                        dateList.Add(startDate)
                        noDays = noDays + 1
                    End If
                Case "Tuesday"
                    If DaysOfWeek.Contains("Monday") Then
                        dateList.Add(startDate)
                        noDays = noDays + 1
                    End If
                Case "Wednesday"
                    If DaysOfWeek.Contains("Wednesday") Then
                        dateList.Add(startDate)
                        noDays = noDays + 1
                    End If
                Case "Thursday"
                    If DaysOfWeek.Contains("Thursday") Then
                        dateList.Add(startDate)
                        noDays = noDays + 1
                    End If
                Case "Friday"
                    If DaysOfWeek.Contains("Friday") Then
                        dateList.Add(startDate)
                        noDays = noDays + 1
                    End If
                Case "Saturday"
                    If DaysOfWeek.Contains("Saturday") Then
                        dateList.Add(startDate)
                        noDays = noDays + 1
                    End If
                Case "Sunday"
                    If DaysOfWeek.Contains("Sunday") Then
                        dateList.Add(startDate)
                        noDays = noDays + 1
                    End If
            End Select
            startDate = startDate.AddDays(1)

        Loop
        method2StopWatch.Stop()
        Label2.Text = (method2StopWatch.ElapsedTicks).ToString() & " " & noDays & " Days"

        noDays = 0
        dateList.Clear()
        startDate = DateTime.Now

        method1StopWatch.Start()
        For Each Day As String In DaysOfWeek.Split(CChar(","))
            Do While (startDate < endDate)
                If startDate.DayOfWeek.ToString() = Day Then
                    noDays = noDays + 1
                    dateList.Add(startDate)
                End If
                startDate = startDate.AddDays(1)
            Loop
            startDate = DateTime.Now
        Next


        method1StopWatch.Stop()
        Label1.Text = (method1StopWatch.ElapsedTicks).ToString() & " " & noDays & " Days"


        noDays = 0
        dateList.Clear()
        startDate = DateTime.Now

        method4StopWatch.Start()
        Dim daysList As New List(Of DayOfWeek)()
        daysList.Add(DayOfWeek.Monday)
        daysList.Add(DayOfWeek.Tuesday)
        daysList.Add(DayOfWeek.Friday)
        Dim datesList As List(Of Date) = GetDayOfWeekDates(startDate, endDate, daysList)
        method4StopWatch.Stop()
        Label4.Text = (method4StopWatch.ElapsedTicks).ToString() & " " & datesList.Count & " Days"

    End Sub

    Public Function GetDayOfWeekDates(startDate As Date, endDate As Date, daysOfWeek As List(Of DayOfWeek)) As List(Of Date)
        Dim liReturn As New List(Of Date)()
        Dim currDay As Date = startDate
        While currDay <= endDate
            If daysOfWeek.Contains(currDay.Date.DayOfWeek) Then
                liReturn.Add(currDay.Date)
            End If
            currDay = currDay.AddDays(1)
        End While
        Return liReturn
    End Function
```

which has resulted in the following output (elapsed ticks) for Mon, Tues, Fri:

```
Method 1 : 10650 - 157 Days
Method 2 : 4152 - 157 Days
Method 3 : 4084 - 157 Days
Method 4 : 179 - 157 Days
```

which also means that my methods and logic were poor.

Comment: So the list contains 7 days at the maximum? What is `List(type date)`? Can you show an example?

Comment: the days parameter holds 7 at maximum, the dateList is open-ended.

Comment: @TimSchmelter List(type date) would be `Dim dateList As New List(Of DateTime)()`

Comment: @kolin update answer with a longer answer which should hopefully have better performance on wide ranges

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is the way I'd do it.  I don't know if it is the most performant way possible, but in my opinion it is the easiest code to read and understand, and should execute quite quickly even if you are checking a large date range.

```
Public Function GetDayOfWeekDates(startDate As Date, endDate As Date, daysOfWeek As List(Of DayOfWeek)) As List(Of Date)
    Dim liReturn As New List(Of Date)()
    Dim currDay As Date = startDate
    While currDay <= endDate
        If daysOfWeek.Contains(currDay.Date.DayOfWeek) Then
            liReturn.Add(currDay.Date)
        End If
        currDay = currDay.AddDays(1)
    End While
    Return liReturn
End Function
```

You would call the function by building a list of DayOfWeek to check against:

```
    Dim daysList As New List(Of DayOfWeek)()
    daysList.Add(DayOfWeek.Monday)
    daysList.Add(DayOfWeek.Friday)
    Dim datesList As List(Of Date) = GetDayOfWeekDates(New Date(2012, 1, 1), New Date(2012, 12, 31), daysList)
```

In this example, your result would be in List(Of Date) datesList.

Edit: I just noticed that you mentioned a web service will receive a comma-delimited list with the days of the week.  In my opinion you should definitely parse the list in a separate function at a level in your code where errors can be returned via the web service if the list is invalid.  The function to find the list of dates should take a strongly typed parameter as I have shown above.

Comment: Congratulations! your method has, so far, proved the fastest, as for parsing the days of the week, i already have functionality built to take care of that, but its worth pointing out.

Comment: Thanks :) I'm glad you separated the parsing routine.  I was just explaining why I felt I shouldn't incorporate the parsing into my method.

Comment: I'm giving @pseudocoder the answer, as it is the one i've used within my code, thanks for helping me out.

Answer (score 2):

**EDIT 2**

I've tested the updated function and I was able to simplify which should also make it a little faster.

```
Public Shared Function DaysOfWeekRange(
    ByVal startDateTime As DateTime, _
    ByVal endDateTime As DateTime, _
    ByVal daysOfWeek As ISet(Of DayOfWeek)) As IEnumerable(Of DateTime)

    If (endDateTime < startDateTime) Then
        Return Enumerable.Empty(Of DateTime)()
    End If

    Dim startDate = startDateTime.Date
    Dim endDate = endDateTime.Date

    Dim firstDate As DateTime?
    Dim lastDate As DateTime
    Dim increment = 0
    Dim increments = New List(Of Integer)(7)

    ' Get Increments
    For d = 0 To 6
       If firstDate.HasValue Then
           increment += 1
           Dim day = startDate.AddDays(d)
           If daysOfWeek.Contains(day.DayOfWeek) Then
               lastDate = day
               increments.Add(increment)
               increment = 0
           End If           
       Else
           Dim possibleFirst = startDate.AddDays(d)
           If daysOfWeek.Contains(possibleFirst.DayOfWeek) Then
               firstDate = possibleFirst
               lastDate = firstDate
           End If
       End If
    Next

    If Not firstDate.HasValue Then
        Return Enumerable.Empty(Of DateTime)()
    End If

    ' Add loop back increment
    increments.Add((7 - lastDate.DayOfWeek) + firstDate.Value.DayOfWeek)

    ' Prepare iteration
    Dim wholeWeeks = Math.Floor(endDate.Subtract(firstDate).TotalDays() /7)
    Dim results = new List(Of DateTime)((wholeWeeks + 1) * daysOfWeek.Count)
    Dim thisDate = firstDate

    ' Whole Weeks
    For i = 1 To wholeWeeks Step 1
        For Each increment In increments
            results.Add(thisDate)
            thisDate = thisDate.AddDays(increment)
        Next
    Next

    ' Last Partial Week
    If (thisDate <= endDate) Then
        For Each increment In Increments
            results.Add(thisDate)
            thisDate = thisDate.AddDays(increment)
            If (thisDate > endDate) Then
                Exit For
            End If
        Next
    End if

    Return results
End Function
```

---

I can think of a more efficient way but, it involves implementing `Enumerator(Of DateTime)`, its a shame we don't have a `yield return` equivalent in Visual Basic, then there would be a simple efficient option. If you want the `Enumerator` option then please ask.

Anyway this function is simple to write and shouldn't be too slow.

```
Public Shared Function DaysOfWeekRange(
    ByVal startDateTime As DateTime, _
    ByVal endDateTime As DateTime, _
    ByVal daysOfWeek As ISet(Of DayOfWeek)) As IEnumerable(Of DateTime)

    If (endDateTime < startDateTime) Then
        Return Enumerable.Empty(Of DateTime)()
    End If

    Dim startDate = startDateTime.Date
    Dim endDate = endDateTime.Date

    Return Enumerable.Range(0, endDate.Subtract(startDate).TotalDays) _
        .Select(Function(i) startDate.AddDays(i)) _
        .Where(Function(day) daysOfWeek.Contains(day.DayOfWeek))
End Function
```

---

**EDIT**

In this approach I calculate the cycle of increments up front and repeat for the number of whole weeks without checks. Then I increment for the last partial week with checks. If the range is sufficiently wide I think this should have a performance adavantage.

```
Public Shared Function DaysOfWeekRange(
    ByVal startDateTime As DateTime, _
    ByVal endDateTime As DateTime, _
    ByVal daysOfWeek As ISet(Of DayOfWeek)) As IEnumerable(Of DateTime)

    If (endDateTime < startDateTime) Then
        Return Enumerable.Empty(Of DateTime)()
    End If

    Dim startDate = startDateTime.Date
    Dim endDate = endDateTime.Date

    Dim firstDate = Enumerable.Range(0, 6) _
        .Select(Function(i) startDate.AddDays(i)) _
        .First(Function(d) daysOfWeek.Contains(d.DayOfWeek))

    Dim firstDayOfWeek = firstDate.DayOfWeek
    Dim offsets = New SortedSet(Of Integer)()
    For Each dayOfWeek in daysOfWeek
       Dim offset = dayOfWeek - firstDayOfWeek

       Select Case offset
           Case Is > 0
               offsets.Add(offset)
           Case Is < 0
               offsets.Add(7 + offset)
       End Select
    Next

    Dim increments = New List(Of Integer)()
    Dim lastOffset = 0
    For Each offset In offsets
        increments.Add(offset - lastOffset)
        lastOffset = offset
    Next
    increments.Add(7 - lastOffset)

    Dim results = new List(Of DateTime)()
    Dim wholeWeeks = Math.Floor(endDate.Subtract(firstDate).TotalDays() /7)
    Dim thisDate = firstDate

    'Whole Weeks
    For i = 1 To wholeWeeks Step 1
        For Each increment In increments
            results.Add(thisDate)
            thisDate = thisDate.AddDays(increment)
        Next
    Next

    'Last Partial Week
    If (thisDate <= endDate) Then
        For Each increment In Increments
            results.Add(thisDate)
            thisDate = thisDate.AddDays(increment)
            If (thisDate > endDate) Then
                Exit For
            End If
        Next
    End if

    Return results
End Function
```

It looks like a lot more code but I think that in most cases the preperation up front results in less work overall.

Comment: Interesting use of of Range() to directly compare both sets.  I think this code could be a little tough to read/debug though, for a relatively simple task.  Due to the lambda expression, AddDays(i) will be called the same number of times as if you had just iterated, so I doubt you will get any performance gain.  I would be interested in seeing your Enumerator<DateTime> solution.  Does it eliminate the need for AddDays()?

Comment: @pseudocoder I agree, this won't be faster but, does it make a difference adding 1 day versus n days? I've got an idea for something quicker...

Comment: @pseudocoder I've edited with another idea, I've not actually tested it but I hope you get the idea.

Comment: +1. I was thinking something like your EDIT version. When I started writing it, I realized the code becomes rather cluttered, and the whole effort / loss of readability may not be worth the performance gain, if any.

Comment: @jodrell i'm going to try and add this to my test page and see what kind of ticks it takes to process

Comment: @kolin I've tested and simplified the function a little in EDIT 2

Comment: Thanks for the ideas, i've made a note of them, and when I get the chance, i'm going to try out your method compared to @pseudocoder method.